# When I submit my registration form it doesn't execute the post controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

I have two different forms in one HTML. One is the Login and it does works, but the other one is Register and when I submit the form it never goes in the post controller for /register action.

**LoginController.java**

```
@Resource
UserFacade userFacade;

@GetMapping("/login")
public String signupForm(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("newuser", new User());
    return "login";
}

@PostMapping("/register")
public User signupSubmit(@ModelAttribute("newuser") User user) {
    userFacade.saveUser(user);
    return user;
}
```

**login.html**, here you can see both forms, the first is the login the one who works and the other one is the register form. When i click on the submit button while debugging it never goes in the public User signupSubmit function that i wrote before.

```
<form id="login-form" th:action="@{/login}" method="post" style="display: block;">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" tabindex="1" class="form-control"
               placeholder="Email" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" tabindex="2" class="form-control"
               placeholder="Contraseña">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="checkbox" tabindex="3" class="" name="remember-me" id="remember"> <label
            for="remember"> Recuérdame</label>
        <div align="center" th:if="${param.error}">
            <p style="font-size: 15; color: #FF1C19;">Email o contraseña incorrectos</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                <input type="submit" name="login-submit" id="login-submit"
                       class="form-control btn btn-login" value="Iniciar sesión">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<!-- ======================= REGISTRO ============================ -->
<form id="register-form" th:action="@{/register}" th:object="${newuser}" method="post" role="form"
      style="display: none;">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" th:field="*{email}" name="email" id="email" class="form-control"
               placeholder="Email" tabindex="1">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" th:field="*{name}" name="name" id="name" class="form-control"
               placeholder="Nombre" tabindex="2">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" th:field="*{lastName}" name="lastName" id="lastName" class="form-control"
               placeholder="Apellido" tabindex="3">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" th:field="*{password}" name="password" id="password"
               class="form-control" placeholder="Contraseña" tabindex="4">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                <input type="submit" name="register-submit" id="register-submit"
                       class="form-control btn btn-register" value="Registrarse">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

My Spring security config

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/css/**", "/js/**", "/images/**", "/vendor/**", "/fonts/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll().and().logout()
                .permitAll().and().rememberMe().key("uniqueAndSecret");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().usersByUsernameQuery("select email, password, active from user where email=?")
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(
                        "select u.email, r.role from user u inner join user_role ur on(u.user_id=ur.user_id) inner join role r on(ur.role_id=r.role_id) where u.email=?")
                .dataSource(dataSource).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }
}


@Configuration
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        return bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    }

}
```

Comment: Of course it won't... You are posting to `/login` not `/register`.

Comment: Even though if I put @PostMapping("/login") it also doesn't works... Instead it executes when I hit the login submit button, not the register submit button

Comment: I missed the fact that there are 2 forms. So ignore that comment. Add your security configuration.

Comment: No problem, added!

Comment: You protected all your URLs... `.anyRequest().authenticated()` hence it will never reach your controller but be stopped by your security rules. You need to permit all access to the `/register` url. You do that by placing a rule **BEFORE** the `.anyRequest().authenticated()` if you don't it still won't have any effect as rules are consulted in the order they are defined in!.

Comment: That has a lot of sense, omg i will try, thank you so much, didn't thought about it

Comment: This solved it! Thank you so much!!! I'm new here so I don't know how to put you as the good answer or give you any kind of karma..

Answer (score 0):

In your security configuration you have protected all of your URLs through adding a single `.anyRequest().authenticated()` and without any further security rules.

Hence you need to be authenticated to access `/register` and as you aren't authorized you are redirected again to the entry page and basically stay in that loop. You need to open up the `/register` URL by adding an additional security rule. Adding `antMatcher("/register").permitAll()` should do the trick.

**NOTE:** When adding security rules the order in which the rules are defined is important. The security rules are also considered in the order they are defined in. So if your `.anyRequest().authenticated()` is the first rule any rule after that is pretty much useless. So take care of the order when adding rules.

```
 @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/css/**", "/js/**", "/images/**", "/vendor/**", "/fonts/**", "/register").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
        .and().logout().permitAll()
        .and().rememberMe().key("uniqueAndSecret");
}
```

Adding the `/register` to the already available `antMatchers` that permits all access will do the trick as well.